# Java InputStreamReader from URL does not encode "Umlaute"

Tags: java, html, url, inputstreamreader

I try to read the html content from an URL. When I wan't to print the content to the console "Umlaute" like ä, ö, ü are displayed wrong.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.lauftreff.de/laeufe/halbmarathon-1-2017.html");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(input);
String inputLine;
while((inputLine = bi.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
```

In the header of the html the information of the charset says ISO_8859_1. Also UTF-8 does not work.
Has anyone an Idea what to do?

Comment: your console does not support UTF-8 or ISO_8859_1?

Comment: You are getting results correctly. However, "ä" is expressed as `&auml;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the website the Umlaute are decoded as HTML entities. So you would need to decode those. The code below should work, but it is untested.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.lauftreff.de/laeufe/halbmarathon-1-2017.html");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(input);
String inputLine;
while((inputLine = bi.readLine()) != null){
    inputLine = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(inputLine);
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I also noticed.

Comment: You should mention where `StringEscapeUtils` came from: it's not part of the JDK.

Comment: Thank you! Added the lang3 to maven dependencies!